# Running exe on Linux w/ mono - access com port

Tags: .net, linux, mono, serial-port

I have an exe file that was written in .NET.  I don't have access to the source code.  I'm trying to run it on a Linux box, through mono.  The exe file is used to push serial data through a USB com port.  One of the arguments for the exe is the com port.  I've been able to install the USB to serial cable in Linux and reference it to com1 using ln -s /dev/ttyUSBn COM1;
I run in Linux shell: ~$ mono XX.exe com1; then I get an error back that appears to be unable to access serial port.  See below:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>    at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.set_ReceivedBytesThreshold (Int32 value) <0x40e36440 + 0x00023> in :0 
>    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:set_ReceivedBytesThreshold (int)
>    at XXXXXXXXXX (System.String comPort, Int32 baudRate) <0x40e359d0 + 0x000cb> in :0 
>    at XXXXXXXXX.ProgramLauncher.Run (System.String[] args) <0x40e1b6f0 + 0x00853> in :0
>
> Total execution time: 00:00:00.0809760

I'm doing this as a proof of concept; to see if this exe can be used as is multi platform.  If I'm way off base here let me know.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: mono 3.0 is very old, please upgrade to 4.2.x at least (e.g. this is the version that ubuntu 16.04 brings by default)

Comment: Running this in a VM on Ubuntu 16.04 mono is 4.4.0.  Same error.  There was some thought that it may be the way Virtual Box  assigns USB ports.  I tried the same on pc running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (I believe) and have the same error.

Comment: seems you found a good bugfix to contribute to an opensource project then